# Thread is quitting

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a little problem with a Thread. I execute the function Receive with time-out set to 600, but it ends here

```
if ((thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running) 
    && (thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
{
  ThreadState st = thr.ThreadState;
  lg.WriteString("EXIT BY THREAD END");
  lg.WriteString("LAST: "+st.ToString());
  break;
}
```

The function should end there only if the thread is over and I have received all the data, but when I open the file errores.txt I see that the ThreadState value is Running or WaitSleepJoin.

Any idea why the function is aborting?

More code below ->

```
bool exit = false;
void WaitAndRead() {
if (buffer == null)
  buffer = new List<byte>();
buffer.Clear();
try
{
  while (sock_client.Available < 1 && !exit)
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  while (sock_client.Available > 0 && !exit)
  {
    byte[] b = new byte[sock_client.Available];
    sock_client.Receive(b, 0, b.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    buffer.AddRange(b);
    Thread.Sleep(25);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
  Log lg = new Log("C:\\TPV\\errores.txt"); 
  lg.WriteException(ex, true); 
}

public int Receive(int timeout,out List<byte> result) 
{
  result = new List<byte>();
  try
  {
    if (!Connected)
      return NOT_CONNECTED;
    bool ok = true;
    ThreadStart str = delegate 
    {
      try { WaitAndRead(); }
      catch (Exception ex) 
      { 
        Log lg = new Log("C:\\TPV\\errores.txt"); 
        lg.WriteException(ex, true); ok = false; }
      };
      exit = false;
      Thread thr = new Thread(str);
      thr.Start();
      int x = 0;
      int max = 10 * timeout;
      while (x < max)
      {
        Log lg = new Log("C:\\TPV\\errores.txt");
        if ((thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running) 
            && (thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
        {
          ThreadState st = thr.ThreadState;
          lg.WriteString("EXIT BY THREAD END");
          lg.WriteString("LAST: "+st.ToString());
          break;
        }
        x++;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
      }
      exit = true;
      if (x >= max)
        return Timeout;
      result = new List<byte>(buffer.ToArray());
      return ok?OK:NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
      Log lg = new Log("C:\\TPV\\errores.txt"); 
      lg.WriteException(ex, true);
      return NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep`s are not good idea

Comment: And what should I use to calculate the time of execution of a thread?

Comment: for basic purposes, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch can be used as an accurate timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be possible that the value of the `ThreadState` property is changing while this code is evaluating:

```
if ((thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running) && (thr.ThreadState != ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
{
    ThreadState st = thr.ThreadState;
    lg.WriteString("EXIT BY THREAD END");
    lg.WriteString("LAST: "+st.ToString());
    break;
}
```

Consider the following scenario:

1. `thr.ThreadState` is `WaitSleepJoin`
2. first part of `if` statement evaluates to `true`
3. `thr.ThreadState` changes to `Running` before second part of `if` is evaluated
4. second part of `if` statement evaluates to `true`
5. since both parts evaluated to `true`, the `if` block is entered

You could try rewriting the code as shown below so you are only checking the value of the `ThreadState` property once:

```
var state = thr.ThreadState;
if (state != ThreadState.Running && state != ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
{
    lg.WriteString("EXIT BY THREAD END");
    lg.WriteString("LAST: "+ state.ToString());
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed some of the notes for the ThreadState property from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx

In particular, it points out that:

> Thread state is only of interest in debugging scenarios. Your code
>   should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of
>   threads.

Do you want to look into using a Monitor or Mutex object instead?

Comment: I didn't know. But mutex didn't aid me much with my task, but while i was searching about it I found that I can wait for a thread to end with the function Join.